# Eror SOQL Didn't understand relationship 'Contact' in FROM part of query call

Tags: apex, soql

> ERROR at Row:1:Column:36  Didn't understand relationship 'Contact' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please r

I have this code,

```java
List<Account> lstAccounts = [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact)
        FROM Account WHERE Name='dickenson plc'];
        
System.debug(lstAccounts);
```

Which is the error?

Comment: As contact is child of account. One Account may have multiple contacts associated with it. Hence it should be `Contacts` not `Contact`

Answer (score 3):

When doing a sub query (the SOQL version of an Inner Join), the FROM clause must reference the *relationship name* you are querying from. This relationship name is defined on the lookup field on the child object. It is usually in the plural form. In this case, the relationship name is `contacts`. Since this is a standard relationship, there is nothing appended to it. Any custom relationship (configured by adding a lookup field from a child object to a parent), will have `__r` appended to the end of it. You'll end up with something like this for a standard relationship like the lookup from Contact to Account:

```sql
SELECT Id, Name, Description, 
  (SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName FROM Contacts)
FROM Account
```

With a custom relationship, it would be something like this, if the Relationship Name defined on that custom lookup field is `children`:

```sql
SELECT Id, MyFieldOnParent__c,
  (SELECT Id, MyFieldOnChild__c FROM Children__r)
FROM MyParentObject__c
```